# How do I add mix in audio from one file to a another

Tags: sound, sox

I'm trying to add background audio to a primary wav file.

```
sox -m primary.wav background.wav output.wav
```

I have about 5s of background chatter in background.wav and I'd like the output to always be at the length of primary. How can I make sox loop and trim background.wav to the length of primary for mixing in shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ffmpeg does it very well. For example:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp3 -i input2.mp3 -filter_complex amerge -ac 2 -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 output.mp3
```

See the FFmpeg manual for [Manipulating audio channels](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation)

Comment: in order to add background wav to my input wav (mono) I used: ffmpeg -i input.wav -i background.wav -filter_complex amerge -ac 1 output.wav